# How to convert blade syntax to php?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

### Goal

My goal is to convert all the blade syntax to PHP.

In my `decode.php`

I converted almost all my blade syntax, but except one minor thing - the **image**.

I am not sure how to go around that.

What I have now :

```
<img src="/img/flags_3/flags/48/{{{ $distributor['hq_country']['name'] or '' }}}.png  " width="20px" height="20px">
```

I am sure that

```
<?php echo isset( $distributor['hq_country']['name'] ) ? $distributor['hq_country']['name'] : '' ?>
```

will give me the same result as

```
{{{ $distributor['hq_country']['name'] or '' }}}
```

I normally use my blade syntax as part of my HTML attribute, but now I can't use the php code in the HTML attribute.

Any suggestion on this ?

Comment: Why can't you use it? What happens?

Comment: It work now. Never mind. I guess, I can use php code within the HTML attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong. After refreshing the page, it's work. 
So yes, we can use php code within HTML attribute.

Here is my final code should look like.

```
<img src="/img/flags_3/flags/48/<?php echo isset( $distributor['hq_country']['name'] ) ? $distributor['hq_country']['name'] : '' ?>.png  " width="20px" height="20px">
```

Answer (score 2):

Run your laravel app and it will be rendered to php in 
\app\storage\views

Answer (score 0):

Something else you may want to consider would be moving the calculation out to it's own line so that it's easier to read:

```
<?php
    $name = '';
    if ( isset($distributor['hq_country']['name']) )
        $name = $distributor['hq_country']['name'];
?>
{{ "<img src='/img/flags_3/flags/48/$name.png' width='20px' height='20px'>" }}
```

It's a little more verbose, but when you come back to look at the code months/years from now it will be a bit easier on the eye.